# Am I making my code too complicated for myself?

Tags: python

I'm currently still learning the basics of Python. I see other people Celsius to Fahrenheit conversions and it's like 10 lines. While my code is over 40 lines. I didn't fully understood what was the point of 'return', so I picked a simple project to understand it. But when I realize my code is super long for something so simple. It feels like I should do much difficult projects, for the amount of lines I'm  using for something simple.

Sorry I'm new and I'm eager to learn by doing projects. Any recommendations of difficult beginner projects would help. Thanks!

```
import time

degree_sign = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'

def fahrenheit():
    degree = int(input('\nHow many degrees is it currently in Fahrenheit?: '))
    a = round((degree - 32) * 5/9)
    
    return a

def celsius():
    degree = int(input('\nHow many dgrees is it currently in Celsius?: '))
    a = round((degree * 9/5) + 32)
    
    return a

print("Welcome to my first weather conversion!\n")

weather = input('Do you want to convert to Fahrenheit or Celsius (c/f)? \n').lower()

if weather == "c":
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(f'It is currently {fahrenheit()}{degree_sign}C.')

elif weather == "f":
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(f'\nIt is currently {celsius()}{degree_sign}F.')

else:
    while True:
        print("\nI'm sorry I don't understand.\n")
        weather = input('Do you want to convert to Fahrenheit or Celsius (c/f)? \n').lower()
        if weather != "c" and weather != "f":
            continue
        elif weather == "c":
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(f'\nIt is currently {fahrenheit()}{degree_sign}C')
            break
        elif weather == "f":
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(f'\nIt is currently {celsius()}{degree_sign}F.')
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time

degree_sign = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'

def fahrenheit():
    degree = int(input('\nHow many degrees is it currently in Fahrenheit?: '))
    a = round((degree - 32) * 5/9)
    
    return a

def celsius():
    degree = int(input('\nHow many dgrees is it currently in Celsius?: '))
    a = round((degree * 9/5) + 32)
    
    return a

print("Welcome to my first weather conversion!\n")

weather = input('Do you want to convert to Fahrenheit or Celsius (c/f)? \n').lower()
d = {"c": f"{fahrenheit()}{degree_sign}C",
     "f": f"{celsius()}{degree_sign}F"}

if weather == "c":
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(f'It is currently {fahrenheit()}{degree_sign}C.')

elif weather == "f":
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(f'\nIt is currently {celsius()}{degree_sign}F.')

else:
    while True:
        print("\nI'm sorry I don't understand.\n")
        weather = input('Do you want to convert to Fahrenheit or Celsius (c/f)? \n').lower()
        try:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("It is currently ", d[weather])
        except:
            continue
```

Similarly you can modify other if-else clauses